# JavaFX controller doesn't read propertie from application.yml

Tags: javafx, yaml, properties-file

I wanna set my global variable from **application.yml** in my **FXML-controller**, but when I look at my variable, **IDE** shows `No documantation found`. How can I put my `bookadd=http://localhost:2345/book/add` propertie into **JavaFX-controller**, using **application.yml** if **JavaFX-controllers** not support creating constructor inside himself?

**env.properties:**

```
app.port=1111
book-add=http://localhost:2345/book/add
```

**LoadBookController**

```
package ru.bookshelf.minimal.frontend;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinition;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import ru.bookshelf.minimal.service.LoadSceneService;

@Component
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class LoadBookController {
    @Value("${bookshelf.add-book-url}")
    private String addBookUrl;

    @FXML
    private Button loadBookBackButton;
    @FXML
    private Button loadBookButton;
    @FXML
    private Button saveBookButton;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    Stage stage = new Stage();

    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        loadBookBackButton.setOnAction(
                actionEvent -> {
                    loader.setControllerFactory(context::getBean);
                    LoadSceneService loadSceneService = new LoadSceneService();
                    loadSceneService.setScene(loader, loadBookButton, "/FXML/loadBook.fxml",
                            stage, "Library");
                });

        loadBookButton.setOnAction(
                actionEvent -> {});
        saveBookButton.setOnAction(
                actionEvent -> {});
    }
}
```

**StartController**

```
package ru.bookshelf.minimal.frontend;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import ru.bookshelf.minimal.service.LoadSceneService;

public class StartController {

  @FXML private Button startButton;

  @FXML
  void initialize() {
    startButton.setOnAction(
        actionEvent -> {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            LoadSceneService loadSceneService = new LoadSceneService();
            loadSceneService.setScene(loader, startButton, "/FXML/loadBook.fxml",
                    stage, "Авторизация");
        });
  }
}
```

**LoadSceneService:**

```
package ru.bookshelf.minimal.service;

import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Hyperlink;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.io.IOException;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class LoadSceneService {
    public void setScene(FXMLLoader loader, Button button, String scene, Stage stage, String title){
        button.getScene().getWindow().hide();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource(scene));

        try {
            loader.load();
            Parent root = loader.getRoot();
            stage.setTitle(title);
            stage.setResizable(false);
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Ошибка в загрузке сцены" + e);
        }
    }
    public void setScene(FXMLLoader loader, Hyperlink link, String scene, Stage stage, String title){
        link.getScene().getWindow().hide();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource(scene));

        try {
            loader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Parent root = loader.getRoot();
        stage.setTitle(title);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.show();
    }
    public void clearFields(TextField firstNameReg,TextField secondNameReg,TextField loginReg,PasswordField passReg, TextField mailReg){
        firstNameReg.clear();
        secondNameReg.clear();
        loginReg.clear();
        passReg.clear();
        mailReg.clear();
    }
}
```

**MinimalApplication**

```
package ru.bookshelf.minimal;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import java.io.IOException;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MinimalApplication extends Application {

    private static Scene scene;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        scene = new Scene(loadFXML("primary"), 1280, 720);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Start menu");
        stage.show();
    }

    static void setRoot(String fxml) throws IOException {
        scene.setRoot(loadFXML(fxml));
    }

    private static Parent loadFXML(String fxml) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader =
                new FXMLLoader(MinimalApplication.class.getResource("/FXML/start.fxml"));
        return fxmlLoader.load();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

**StartJavaFX**

```
package ru.bookshelf.minimal;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

//This main-class needs to start application using JavaFX dependencies
@SpringBootApplication
public class StartJavaFX {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MinimalApplication.main(args);
    }
}
```

**loadBook.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="1280.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/15.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="ru.bookshelf.minimal.frontend.LoadBookController">
   <children>
      <ImageView fitHeight="720.0" fitWidth="1280.0">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../assets/4.jpg" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <Button fx:id="loadBookBackButton" layoutX="1174.0" layoutY="615.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="65.0" prefWidth="67.0" stylesheets="@../css/Styles.css" text="Назад" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font size="15.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Button fx:id="loadBookButton" layoutX="610.0" layoutY="304.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="53.0" prefWidth="285.0" stylesheets="@../css/Styles.css" text="Загрузить книгу" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font size="24.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <Label layoutX="525.0" layoutY="226.0" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="408.0" text="Вы можете загрузить свою книгу просто нажав" textFill="#ababab">
         <font>
            <Font name="Web Serveroff Regular" size="24.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="501.0" layoutY="263.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="499.0" text="на соответствующую кнопку и выбрав необходимый файл" textFill="#ababab">
         <font>
            <Font name="Web Serveroff Regular" size="24.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <TextField fx:id="tbAuthor" layoutX="329.0" layoutY="271.0" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="154.0" stylesheets="@../css/Styles.css" />
      <Label fx:id="labelAuthor" layoutX="329.0" layoutY="239.0" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="49.0" text="Автор" textFill="#ababab">
         <font>
            <Font name="Web Serveroff Regular" size="24.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <TextField fx:id="tbTitle" layoutX="329.0" layoutY="340.0" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="154.0" stylesheets="@../css/Styles.css" />
      <Label fx:id="labelTitle" layoutX="329.0" layoutY="308.0" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Название" textFill="#ababab">
         <font>
            <Font name="Web Serveroff Regular" size="24.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label fx:id="labelPublishDate" layoutX="329.0" layoutY="376.0" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="154.0" text="Дата публикации" textFill="#ababab">
         <font>
            <Font name="Web Serveroff Regular" size="24.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Button fx:id="saveBookButton" layoutX="610.0" layoutY="386.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="53.0" prefWidth="285.0" stylesheets="@../css/Styles.css" text="Сохранить книгу" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font size="24.0" />
         </font>
      </Button>
      <DatePicker fx:id="dpPublish_date" layoutX="329.0" layoutY="413.0" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="154.0" promptText="01.01.2020" stylesheets="@../css/Styles.css" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**start.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="1280.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/15.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="ru.bookshelf.minimal.frontend.StartController">
   <children>
      <ImageView fitHeight="720.0" fitWidth="1280.0">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../assets/1.jpg" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <Button fx:id="startButton" layoutX="555.0" layoutY="393.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="104.0" prefWidth="170.0" stylesheets="@../css/Styles.css" text="Войти" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="WHITE">
         <font>
            <Font name="Web Serveroff Regular" size="45.0" />
         </font></Button>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**application.yml**

```
client:
  port: ${app.port}
  forward-headers-strategy: framework

bookshelf:
  add-book-url: ${book-add}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>ru.bookshelf</groupId>
    <artifactId>minimal</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>minimal</name>
    <description>minimal</description>


    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.testresult.directory>${project.build.directory}/test-results</project.testresult.directory>

        <spring.boot.version>2.6.1</spring.boot.version>
        <thymeleaf-spring5.version>3.1.0.M1</thymeleaf-spring5.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.22</lombok.version>
        <javafx.version>15.0.1</javafx.version>
        <springdoc.swagger.version>1.5.13</springdoc.swagger.version>
        <unirest.version>1.4.9</unirest.version>
        <jackson.version>2.13.0</jackson.version>
        <commons.io.version>2.11.0</commons.io.version>
        <spring.test.version>5.3.16</spring.test.version>


        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven-clean-plugin.version>3.1.0</maven-clean-plugin.version>
        <maven-resources-plugin.version>3.1.0</maven-resources-plugin.version>
        <properties-maven-plugin.version>1.0.0</properties-maven-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <build.env.dir>dev</build.env.dir>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
    </profiles>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- thymeleaf-spring5 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
            <version>${thymeleaf-spring5.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- spring web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- web flux -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-netty</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- lombok-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- javafx -->
        <!-- javafx-controls -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- javafx-fxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- javafx-base -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- javafx-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- javafx-graphics -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--Swagger-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springdoc.swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- unirest -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
            <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
            <version>${unirest.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- MockMultipartFile-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.test.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- jackson-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>${commons.io.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--tests-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>


                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.version}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>


                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${properties-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>initialize</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <files>
                                    <file>
                                        ${project.basedir}/src/env/${build.env.dir}/env.properties
                                    </file>
                                </files>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>


                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-resources-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>generate-resources</id>
                            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>resources</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <resources>
                                    <resource>
                                        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                                    </resource>
                                </resources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>


                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>repackage</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <mainClass>ru.bookshelf.minimal.StartJavaFX</mainClass>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: Is this Spring? If so, you need to tell your `FXMLLoader` to get the controller from the spring application context. You haven't posted the code where the FXML is loaded, so it's not easy to give a solution, but basically you do this by setting the controller factory. There are lots of examples on this site, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48290589/javafx-spring-boot-npe). Also note your controllers [should have prototype scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44391456/spring-in-a-javafx-application-how-to-property-handle-controller-as-dependency).

Comment: @James_D I edited my post, added LoadSceneService. I have a lot of FXML-scenes and just create service, which load new scene when method is calling

Comment: Please create and post a [mre].

Comment: @James_D I maded minimal reproducible example, please can you check it

Comment: OK, but as I said in a previous comment, you have to tell the `FXMLLoader` to get the controller instances from Spring. See the duplicate question.

Comment: @James_D can you write what i should add to my StartController, i read your previous question, but dont understand what is 
 " Autowired
   private ApplicationContext context ;" and where i can get it in my code

Comment: What's not to understand? Presumably if you're using Spring, you know what `@Autowired` and `ApplicationContext` are (if not, you need to read a tutorial; this is not the place to ask for complete intro tutorials in the technology you  are using). I don't know what you mean by "where I can get it in my code".

Comment: @James_D I change my LoadBookController, add context and load bean's using setControllerFactory, but addBookUrl still null when I run my app. I understand correctly that I should put a bean with an "Value" annotation into context to Spring can initialaze it ?